# In a ServiceNow pivot table, how do you sort descending by count?

Tags: servicenow

In ServiceNow, you can clearly sort pivot tables by any of the available fields.  Also the pivot table visualization will clearly calculate the total count (the last column of the pivot table), however, there doesn't seem to be a method for sorting by that calculated total count (e.g. - if the pivot table calculates the following (Image from ServiceNow documentation):

[image]

I want to know how to sort by the "Total" column (descending) so that ITIL User is listed first, then David Loo, then Beth Anglin, etc..

Thank you.